# Facebook auth runs into a generic error?

Tags: javascript, facebook, html, facebook-graph-api, oauth

My app was running fine yesterday. I haven't changed any of the code, but now for some reason I get `An error occurred with [app name]. Please try again later.` when I try to log in.

I had changed some of the settings for the app through the development interface. The first thing I did to remedy the problem was to undo all those changes but I'm still getting the error.

The app also works fine authenticating if you're already logged in to Facebook, it's just when you need to be redirected to the login screen that it throws this error instead of letting the user authenticate.

Any Ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What URL did you specify in you app's settings on facebook?  Is it set to the correct mysite.com url there?  What I do is I have 1 app for my dev environment, 1 for my test/qa environment, and 1 app for prod environment.  This way I don't have too worry about overlap or changing settings.  Set once and forget.  Maybe you could benefit from such a setup.  Maybe your SSL cert expired?  So many things could be different.  Hard to tell.

Comment: How can I even go about debugging this? Error message gives me no lead except to try again later....

Comment: Nope, it didn't help solve the problem. I know how to mark answers, don't leave comments like this.

Comment: Just a courteous followup, fancy, that's all.  Have you tried creating a different Facebook app and using the new ID/Secret?  Have you verified you SSL cert is still valid?

Comment: Have you had a chance to try creating a different Facebook app and using the new ID/Secret? Have you verified you SSL cert is still valid?